# Django Form: Field not saving after form submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form which has 2 ModelChoiceFields and 1 ChoiceField. The ModelChoiceFields are saving after form submission, but the ChoiceField is not. The field that is not saving is the `condition` field.

**Form in views.py:**

```
class TradeCreateForm(LoginRequiredMixin, forms.Form):
    the_game_you_own = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Game.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='owned',
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='game-autocomplete',
            attrs={
                'data-minimum-input-length': 2, #res, sp
            },
        )
    )

    condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Trade.CONDITION_CHOICES, initial='OK - 1 or 2 small scratches', label='...', required=True)

    the_game_you_want_in_exchange = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Game.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='desired',
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='game-autocomplete',
            attrs={
                'data-minimum-input-length': 2,
            },
        )
    )
```

**models.py:**

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    CONDITION_CHOICES = (
        ('Bad - A lot of scratches', 'Bad - A lot of scratches'),
        ('OK - 1 or 2 small scratches', 'OK - 1 or 2 small scratches'),
        ('Good - No scratches, 1 or 2 smudges', 'Good - No scratches, 1 or 2 smudges'),
        ('Perfect - No scratches, no smudges', 'Perfect - No scratches, no smudges'),
    )

    name = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)   
    owned_game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owned_game', db_column='owned_game')
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CONDITION_CHOICES)

    desired_game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='desired_game', db_column='desired_game')

    def get_trade_name(self):
        return ''.join([self.user_who_posted.username, '(', timezone.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S UTC"), ')'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.get_trade_name()
        super(Trade, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # return game name when game.objects.all() is called
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I was handling the update of this object in the function called in the action method of the form